# 33mfailed action with response of 400, dropping action - logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to use elasticsearch + logstash (jdbc input).

my elasticsearch seems to be ok. The problem seems to be in logstash (elasticsearch output plugin).

my logstash.conf:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "C:\DEV\elasticsearch-1.7.1\plugins\elasticsearch-jdbc-1.7.1.0\lib\sqljdbc4.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=dbTest"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "pass"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT ID_RECARGA as _id FROM RECARGA where DT_RECARGA >= '2015-09-04'"
    jdbc_paging_enabled => "true"
    jdbc_page_size => "50000"
  }
}
filter {
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => "localhost"
    protocol => "http"
    index => "test_index"
    document_id => "%{objectId}"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

when I run the log stash:

```
C:\DEV\logstash-1.5.4\bin>logstash -f logstash.conf
```

I'm getting this result:

```
←[33mfailed action with response of 400, dropping action: ["index", {:_id=>"%{ob
jectId}", :_index=>"parrudo", :_type=>"logs", :_routing=>nil}, #<LogStash::Event
:0x5d4c2abf @metadata_accessors=#<LogStash::Util::Accessors:0x900a6e7 @store={"r
etry_count"=>0}, @lut={}>, @cancelled=false, @data={"_id"=>908026, "@version"=>"
1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-09-04T21:19:00.322Z"}, @metadata={"retry_count"=>0}, @ac
cessors=#<LogStash::Util::Accessors:0x4929c6a4 @store={"_id"=>908026, "@version"
=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-09-04T21:19:00.322Z"}, @lut={"type"=>[{"_id"=>908026,
 "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-09-04T21:19:00.322Z"}, "type"], "objectId"
=>[{"_id"=>908026, "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-09-04T21:19:00.322Z"}, "
objectId"]}>>] {:level=>:warn}←[0m
{
           "_id" => 908026,
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-09-04T21:19:00.322Z"
}
{
           "_id" => 908027,
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-09-04T21:19:00.322Z"
}
{
           "_id" => 908028,
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-09-04T21:19:00.323Z"
}
{
           "_id" => 908029,
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-09-04T21:19:00.323Z"
}
```

In elasticsearch the index was created but have any docs.

I'm using windows and MSSql Server.

elasticsearch version: 1.7.1
logstash version: 1.5.4
any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right... after looking fot this erros in elasticsearch log I realize that the problem was the alias in my sql statement.

statement => "SELECT ID_RECARGA as _id FROM RECARGA where DT_RECARGA >= '2015-09-04'"

For some reason that I don't know It wasn't been processed, so I just remove this from my query and everything seems to be right now.

thanks!